# Search missing timestamp in pandas time series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series with a timestamp and some values. The data is coming in approximately every 5 minutes plus/minus. But on some days there aren't any timestamps at all or maybe the first timestamp might only be around 3 pm etc. How can I visualize/analyze the gaps?

```
timestamp            temp
2016-08-02 00:14:01  12.1
2016-08-02 09:05:04  22.0
2016-08-02 09:09:44  12.9
2016-08-02 09:15:01  44.1
2016-08-02 09:19:54  11.3
```

Comment: Are you just trying to plot your data? Matplotlib should be able to handle spacing of dates if that is what you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a *time difference* column to your *df*:

```
df['tDiff'] = df.timestamp.diff()
```

Then, to find rows with "too big" time gap from the previous one, run:

```
df[df.tDiff > pd.Timedelta('6M')]
```

Of course, it is a matter of choice how to set the threshold timedelta.
Instead of *6 min* you can take another value.

For the test, I extended slightly your data:

```
             timestamp  temp
0  2016-08-02 00:14:01  12.1
1  2016-08-02 09:05:04  22.0
2  2016-08-02 09:09:44  12.9
3  2016-08-02 09:15:01  44.1
4  2016-08-02 09:19:54  11.3
5  2016-08-02 23:58:54  10.0
6  2016-08-03 00:04:01  12.1
7  2016-08-03 09:05:04  22.0
8  2016-08-03 09:09:44  12.9
9  2016-08-03 09:15:01  44.1
10 2016-08-03 09:19:54  11.3
```

For this data, the result is:

```
            timestamp  temp    tDiff
1 2016-08-02 09:05:04  22.0 08:51:03
5 2016-08-02 23:58:54  10.0 14:39:00
7 2016-08-03 09:05:04  22.0 09:01:03
```

So e.g. the reading as of *2016-08-02 09:05:04* occurred after over 8 hours
after the previous reading.

## Edit following the comment

For graphic presentation of gaps, another approach can be more useful.

1. Add *previous timestamp* column (insead of *tDiff*):

   ```
   df['tPrev'] = df.timestamp.shift()
   ```
2. Create a DataFrame with "start of the gap" and "end of the gap" columns:

   ```
   gaps = df[(df.timestamp - df.tPrev) > pd.Timedelta('6M')][['tPrev', 'timestamp']]
   ```

For my source data the result is:

```
                tPrev           timestamp
1 2016-08-02 00:14:01 2016-08-02 09:05:04
5 2016-08-02 09:19:54 2016-08-02 23:58:54
7 2016-08-03 00:04:01 2016-08-03 09:05:04
```

But the matter of how to generate such a picture is rather a good material
for **another** question.

Comment: That's a good approach! I want to visualize how big the gaps are. Something like a straight line with gaps in it over the time of a day for example, so that you have a visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```
df["dtime"]= df.timestamp.diff()                                                                                     

            timestamp  temp    dtime
0 2016-08-02 00:14:01  12.1      NaT
1 2016-08-02 09:05:04  22.0 08:51:03
2 2016-08-02 09:09:44  12.9 00:04:40
3 2016-08-02 09:15:01  44.1 00:05:17
4 2016-08-02 09:19:54  11.3 00:04:53
```